# Who needs the conditional (ternary) operator?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference in JavaScript between the following two expressions?

[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
x > y ? a : b
```

Boolean expression:

```
x > y && a || b
```

Comment: it is. please check zero for `a`.

Comment: Or any false-y value.

Answer (score 3):

Lets write a simple comparisonment table of ***all possible*** (reasonable) scenarios:

```js
console.log("x > y ? a : b")
console.log( 
1 ? 1 : 0,
0 ? 1 : 0,
1 ? 0 : 1,
0 ? 0 : 1 
)

console.log("x > y && a || b")
console.log( 
1 && 1 || 0,
0 && 1 || 0, 
1 && 0 || 1,
0 && 0 || 1 
)
```

Not the same. As you can see `1 ? 0 : 1` is **not the same** as `1 && 0 || 1`. the logic is simply not identical and pretty might self-explanatory.

`true ? a : b` will select `a` because by definition, if `true` then `a`, else `b`.

`true && a || b` is very different - if `true` then evaluate `a || b`, else `false`